# What is the difference between deps and dev-deps in Poetry?

Tags: python-poetry

In the *pyproject.toml* configuration file of Poetry you can specify both `dependencies` and `dev-dependencies`, but the documentation does not state clearly what the difference is.

I guess from the name the *dev-dependencies* will not be installed by a release build, but I didn't notice any difference. How do you use these fields correctly, for example exclude the *dev-dependencies* in a build?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your assumption is right. The best use case for dev-dependencies is when you creating a library with optional dependencies. For instance, you are developing ORM which should work with MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. You have to test that your code is working with all of these RDBMS. You put it into dev-dependencies. But for one, who installs your library, these dependencies are optional and they wouldn't be installed automatically.

Commonly, all libraries that are used for testing or building your application are presented at dev-dependencies.

> How do you use these fields correctly, for example exclude the dev-dependencies in a build?

`poetry install` has a `no-dev` flag for exactly that scenario.

Comment: I am surprised that `no-dev` is not the default. I would guess 95% of user installing a package are not interested in development libraries like pyflakes, pytest, black, etc. But because poetry installs the development packages by default, I have to include instructions to the user to use the `no-dev` flag when installing.

Comment: According to Poetry docs: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install "The `--no-dev` option is now deprecated. You should use the `--without dev` notation instead."